# Python: \n outside of single quotes

Tags: python, string

During a query in pandas, I noticed that some of the strings that I was using had a newline 'outside' of the single quotes, e.g. 'string'\n. The actual console output looks like this:

```
KeyError: "['Alabama' 'Alabama' 'Alabama' 'Alabama' 'Alabama' 'Alabama' 'Alabama'\n 'Alabama' 'Alaska' 'Arizona' 'Arizona' 'Arizona' 'Arkansas' 'Arkansas'\n 'Arkansas' 'Arkansas' 'Arkansas' 'Arkansas' ...
```

I'm already using strip with ' \n' (I want to remove spaces and newlines) on the strings. How do I get rid of these newlines (and what do they mean?)?

**edit**: code snippets and dataframe infos. I should add that I'm a pandas novice and my way of querying is possilby not correct but I want to limit this question to the \n problem

actual query:

```
df_q[df_u['State']]
```

df_q.info(): df_q is multiindexed by 'State', 'RegionName'

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 10730 entries, (New York, New York) to (Wisconsin, Holland)
Data columns (total 7 columns):
2008q3         9884 non-null float64
2008q4         9885 non-null float64
2009q1         9912 non-null float64
2009q2         9930 non-null float64
2009q3         10078 non-null float64
2009q4         10089 non-null float64
is uni town    10730 non-null bool
dtypes: bool(1), float64(6)
memory usage: 597.3+ KB
```

df_u.info():

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 517 entries, 1 to 566
Data columns (total 2 columns):
State         517 non-null object
RegionName    517 non-null object
dtypes: object(2)
memory usage: 12.1+ KB
```

Comment: can you share code snippet as well ?

Comment: I've added infos on the dfs + the query that produced the error. Please tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, string literals can be enclosed in matching single quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`).
If you open your string with double quote, single quote would be just a char in your string:

```
my_singleq_str = "'a\n'a\n'a"
print(my_singleq_str)
# 'a
# 'a
# 'a
```

Thus, single quote (or double quote) does not necessarily mean the string boundary.

As for the newline char - `strip` method removes this char only from the beginning and the end:

```
s = "\n['Alabama'\n 'Alaska']\n"
print(repr(s)) # "\n['Alabama'\n 'Alaska']\n"
print(repr(s.strip())) # "['Alabama'\n 'Alaska']"
```

To remove all newline characters from your string, use `replace` method:

```
s = "\n['Alabama'\n 'Alaska']\n"
print(s.replace('\n','')) # ['Alabama' 'Alaska']
```